# How to create a multi-index pivot table that sums the max values within a sub-group

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a somewhat large dataframe of customers assigned to a hub and each hub is in a specific location. The hubs get flagged whenever there's an issue and I'd like to know the number of customers affected each time this happens.

So I'd like to find the max number of customers assigned to each hub (this would then exclude the times the hub may have been flagged multiple times) and then group the rows by location and the columns by type, then show the sum of the max count of customers over a period of months.

The data looks like:

| Hub | Location | DateTime | Month | Type | Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J01 | NY | 01/01/2022 | January | Type 1 | 250 |
| J03 | CA | 01/21/2022 | January | Type 2 | 111 |
| J01 | NY | 04/01/2022 | April | Type 1 | 250 |
| J05 | CA | 06/01/2022 | June | Type 1 | 14 |
| J03 | CA | 08/18/2022 | August | Type 2 | 111 |

I did the following code to generate a pivot table and it generates the max values for each hub, but there are hundreds of hubs.

```
`    pd.pivot_table (out,values='Customers',index=['Location','Hub'], columns=
     ['Type','Month'],aggfunc='max')    `
```

Results mostly look like:

|  | Type | Type 1 |  |  | Type 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Month** | January | February | March | January |
| **Location** | **Hub** |  |  |  | NA |
| NY | J01 | 0 | 250 | 250 | NA |
|  | J04 | 222 | 222 | 222 | NA |
| CA | J03 | NA | NA | NA | 111 |
| CA | J05 | 14 | 14 | 0 | NA |

I would like the results to look like:

|  | Type | Type 1 |  |  | Type 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Month** | January | February | March | January |
| **Location** |  |  |  |  |  |
| NY |  | 222 | 472 | 472 | 0 |
| CA |  | 14 | 14 | 0 | 111 |

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right start! `pivot_table` is the right way to group the table with columns by type. You also identified that you can perform the `max` aggregation at pivot-time:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(
    out,
    values='Customers',
    index=['Location','Hub'],
    columns=['Type','Month'],
    aggfunc='max'
)
```

Next, we need to groupby `Location` and add (sum) the values:

```
df = df.groupby("Location").max()
```

The final result (trying to build a table that matches your data):

```
out = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Hub Location    DateTime    Month   Type    Customers
J01 NY  01/01/2022  January Type 1  250
J03 CA  01/21/2022  January Type 2  111
J01 NY  04/01/2022  April   Type 1  250
J04 NY  01/01/2022  January Type 1  222
J04 NY  02/01/2022  February    Type 1  222
J04 NY  04/01/2022  April   Type 1  222
J05 CA  06/01/2022  June    Type 1  14
J03 CA  08/18/2022  August  Type 2  111
"""), sep='\t')

pd.pivot_table(
    out,
    values='Customers',
    index=['Location','Hub'],
    columns=['Type','Month'],
    aggfunc='max'
).groupby("Location").sum()
```

gives:

```
    Type    Type 1  Type 2
   Month    April   February    January June    August  January
Location                        
      CA    0.0     0.0         0.0     14.0    111.0   111.0
      NY    472.0   222.0       472.0   0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how does this sum the max customer counts from each specific hub under a particular location? Wouldn't this just return the max customer count per location only?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I missed that part in my first read, it's updated now.